# Curl request working on localhost but not online

Tags: php, curl

when i am sending request on localhost using curl and php it got success as given below

This request is on localhost and get the output which is required to me

```
$url = "https://live12p.hotstar.com/hls/live/2024725/ipl2021/hin/1540008470/15mindvrm01c6817544da534447ba5b5f3760666fd923september2021/master_7.m3u8";
$referer = "https://www.hotstar.com/";
$origin = "https://www.hotstar.com";
$host = "live12p.hotstar.com";

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = 'Host: ' . $host;
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0';
$headers[] = 'Cookie: hs_uid=5221b879-8857-496d-80bd-691646c0fcae; ajs_anonymous_id=%22e1cac957-8325-4cc5-a4c7-04c9322a50b5%22; ajs_user_id=%22971450d482ae40088b5d834ff952f60b%22; ajs_group_id=null; hdntl=exp=1632448848~acl=*ipl2021*~id=5267bf12e30107702f21c2ea2bf8b874~data=ip%3dwzSX5TdVuh1sa432PD6kIOuXAlfHJY32Vve29D3csZOD8xO2AjRrZpV-userid%3d8kP6OEf3LRYFUhAWTlF2R7ooxuElWlYpTzzEAosrFQCW-did%3dYfixYiH5EvZpALjGAYAzylXejGbgnbBi0BBLUmB93Jgj3HHJzJjbH16-~hmac=3508bd69101ca28bef6b9bb4ff4fb833c344404e3d62968cb38bcabb1d756a71';
$headers[] = 'Referer: ' . $referer;
$headers[] = 'Origin: ' . $origin;


// 


$response = get_web_page($url);
echo $response;

function get_web_page($url)
{
    global $referer;
    global $headers;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $verbose = fopen('curl.txt', 'w+');
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_REFERER => $referer,   
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,  
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "gzip, deflate, br", 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0",
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => true,   
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST    => 2,    
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE    => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_STDERR    => $verbose,   
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content  = curl_exec($ch);
    rewind($verbose);
    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
    echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
    
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        // this would be your first hint that something went wrong
        die('Couldn\'t send request: ' . curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        // check the HTTP status code of the request
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($resultStatus != 200) {
            die('Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

this time the output is what i want

```
*   Trying 2600:140f:5800::17d7:d73a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to live12p.hotstar.com (2600:140f:5800::17d7:d73a) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=IN; ST=Maharashtra; L=Mumbai; O=Novi Digital Entertainment Pvt. Ltd.; CN=*.hotstar.com
*  start date: Jul  5 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 13 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "live12p.hotstar.com" matched cert's "*.hotstar.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /hls/live/2024725/ipl2021/hin/1540008470/15mindvrm01c6817544da534447ba5b5f3760666fd923september2021/master_7.m3u8 HTTP/1.1
Host: live12p.hotstar.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Cookie: hs_uid=5221b879-8857-496d-80bd-691646c0fcae; ajs_anonymous_id=%22e1cac957-8325-4cc5-a4c7-04c9322a50b5%22; ajs_user_id=%22971450d482ae40088b5d834ff952f60b%22; ajs_group_id=null; hdntl=exp=1632448848~acl=*ipl2021*~id=5267bf12e30107702f21c2ea2bf8b874~data=ip%3dwzSX5TdVuh1sa432PD6kIOuXAlfHJY32Vve29D3csZOD8xO2AjRrZpV-userid%3d8kP6OEf3LRYFUhAWTlF2R7ooxuElWlYpTzzEAosrFQCW-did%3dYfixYiH5EvZpALjGAYAzylXejGbgnbBi0BBLUmB93Jgj3HHJzJjbH16-~hmac=3508bd69101ca28bef6b9bb4ff4fb833c344404e3d62968cb38bcabb1d756a71
Referer: https://www.hotstar.com/
Origin: https://www.hotstar.com

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Akamai-Path-Timestamp: i=1632413538.914;xi=1632413538.921;xo=1632413540.009;s=1632413540.017;
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Length: 1898
< Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Sep 2021 16:12:18 GMT
< X-Akamai-Live-Origin-QoS: d=4000;t=1632413538.918
< X-Akamai-Server: Akamai-SMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Akamai-Mon-Iucid-Ing: 2024725
< Expires: Thu, 23 Sep 2021 16:12:21 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Thu, 23 Sep 2021 16:12:21 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.hotstar.com
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Server,range,hdntl,hdnts,Akamai-Mon-Iucid-Ing,Akamai-Mon-Iucid-Del,X-Reference-Error,X-ErrorType
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin,range,hdntl,hdnts,X-allowRequest
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
```

but this time when i am sending this request online from [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) then the output is 403 Forbidden Why?

```
Verbose information:

* Added hotstar.com:2600:140f:5800::17d7:d73a to DNS cache
*   Trying 23.37.230.73:443...
* Connected to live12p.hotstar.com (23.37.230.73) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=IN; ST=Maharashtra; L=Mumbai; O=Novi Digital Entertainment Pvt. Ltd.; CN=*.hotstar.com
*  start date: Jul  5 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 13 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "live12p.hotstar.com" matched cert's "*.hotstar.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /hls/live/2024725/ipl2021/hin/1540008470/15mindvrm01c6817544da534447ba5b5f3760666fd923september2021/master_7.m3u8 HTTP/1.1
Host: live12p.hotstar.com
Accept: */*
Cookie: hs_uid=5221b879-8857-496d-80bd-691646c0fcae; ajs_anonymous_id=%22e1cac957-8325-4cc5-a4c7-04c9322a50b5%22; ajs_user_id=%22971450d482ae40088b5d834ff952f60b%22; ajs_group_id=null; hdntl=exp=1632451493~acl=*ipl2021*~id=e1acc4c006ec4a10fb2422774e4b9806~data=ip%3dwzSX5TdVuh1sa432PD6kIOuXAlfHJY32Vve29D3csZOD8xO2AjRrZpV-userid%3d8kP6OEf3LRYFUhAWTlF2R7ooxuElWlYpTzzEAosrFQCW-did%3dYfixYiH5EvZpALjGAYAzylXejGbgnbBi0BBLUmB93Jgj3HHJzJjbH16-~hmac=c9248d2c8ea8b9e0420ad176918a1ea25561bab8af14b444594515491d00fb6e
Referer: https://www.hotstar.com/
Origin: https://www.hotstar.com
X-FORWARDED-FOR: 223.190.135.254

* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: AkamaiGHost
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 416
< X-Reference-Error: 18.45e62517.1632413497.90e1a77
< Expires: Thu, 23 Sep 2021 16:11:37 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Thu, 23 Sep 2021 16:11:37 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Country: IN
< X-ErrorType: geo-blocked
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.hotstar.com
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Server,range,hdntl,hdnts,Akamai-Mon-Iucid-Ing,Akamai-Mon-Iucid-Del,X-Reference-Error,X-ErrorType
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin,range,hdntl,hdnts,X-allowRequest
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
< 
* Connection #0 to host live12p.hotstar.com left intact

Request failed: HTTP status code: 403
```

I don't know why this is happening and how can i solve it
if any one have idea please help me to solve this

Comment: It does not like your host. `Country: IN | X-ErrorType: geo-blocked`

Answer (score 2):

The service you're trying to access is behind Akamai's network and it appears they're geo restricting access.

Note the response header:
`X-ErrorType: geo-blocked`

Comment: then why it is coming only on online not on localhost

Comment: @KumarAditya presumably because your server is in a different country than your localhost

Comment: @ADyson How can i change it using curl in request? I need India server request but server is of US

Comment: You can't change it in curl. You will need to find a server in a different country that isn't blocked.

Comment: @KumarAditya how do you imagine curl can change the location of your server? It cannot put it on a ship and move it to India. We get some strange questions on Stackoverflow but I have to say that is one of the strangest!

Comment: @ADyson thanks! for response i 'll find it self.

Comment: @KumarAditya if you are in control of the server then maybe you can configure a VPN for outbound requests or something. If it's a shared server then you'll need to find another server in a more suitable location